# Adding secure tag to rails 5.2.x API only session cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, csrf, rails-api

I am using a rails API only setup for a project.
I have managed to get it to use custom cookie information, however I CANNOT seem to get it to add the secure tag even though in production the server is on an HTTPS connection.

This is causing my cookies to not get saved since the api is not on the same url as the front end.

here is the setup for the cookies

```
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore

config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, :key => '_session_id', same_site: :none, secure: :true, expire_after: 14.days, httponly: true
```

I also tried secure: Rails.env.production? to no success

For reference here is the session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: session_params[:email])

    if @user && @user.authenticate(session_params[:password])
        login!
        render json: {
            logged_in: true,
            user: @user
        }
        response.set_header('Set-Cookie', 'Secure; SameSite=None')

    else
        render json: {
            status: 401,
            errors: ['no such user', 'verify credentials and try again']
        }
    end
end

def is_logged_in?
    if logged_in? && current_user
        render json: {
            logged_in: true,
            user: current_user
        }
    else
        render json: {
            logged_in: false,
            message: 'no session found'
        }
    end
end

def destroy
    logout!
    render json: {
        status: 200,
        logged_out: true
    }
end

private

def session_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
end
```

end

Image added for comment:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the actual response header? Is it not set with secure, or is it your useragent disregarding that?

Comment: I added an image to the bottom showing what the response header has in chrome dev tools. The parts with actual cookie session ids (removed) are not getting the secure tag but the first set cookie shows secure; samesite=none